# How Does the Positive Feedback Bring an Oscillator's Poles on the Imaginary Axis?

Tags: amplifier, oscillator, feedback, oscillation, positive-feedback

In an oscillator, there is a positive feedback that injects energy into the system in order to sustain the oscillations. This feedback places the system's poles on the imaginary axis. I'd like to know how the math works, and how exactly the feedback moves the poles from the left half plane on the imaginary axis.

Comment: It isn't clear what part of the math you don't understand.  It's a basic feedback oscillator; you can do the feedback equations on it and see the poles move.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @TimWescott Just an explanation of the math. I don’t get it how the feedback moves the poles on the imaginary axis. How does the root locus work?

Comment: "How does root locus work" is way too broad a question for Stackexchange.  I just checked one of my 3rd-year controls textbooks -- that's a question that's answered after you've spent the better part of a semester learning about how the Laplace transform works, and then feedback.

Comment: It is a double integrator with negative feedback. The problem is that the poles can be slightly to the left of the imaginary axis, or slightly to the right of the imaginary axis.  In the first case, the output decays.  In the second case, the output grows (unstable).  It takes some additional control to stabilize the oscillation amplitude.

Comment: Are you talking about the Barkhausen criterion for oscillation or some specific type of oscillator? Most real oscillators rely on nonlinearities to achieve stable oscillation.

Comment: @jDAQ could you briefly explain how a nonlinearity can help sustain the oscillations? Also about the Bakhausen criterion, why should the loop gain be equal to 1? In a closed loop system, the loop gain that places the poles on the imaginary axis can be anything depending on the transfer function of the open loop system.

Answer (score 3):

For oscillators you can either have [linear or relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_oscillator) (nonlinear) ones.

For the nonlinear ones, usually you have some type of hysteresis behavior (although this is not a general definition!).
Two examples I can give are the [Multivibrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator) and the [555 IC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC). The have two operational modes one "charges" and the other one "discarges", and since the transition from charge->discharge and discharge->charge are not at the same point, say,
charge->discharge @ 5V and discharge->charge @ 2V. The system would oscillate between 5 and 2 V, with some waveform that probably is not a pure sinusoidal.

This type of oscillation is usually pretty "self-sustainable" because is is related to some property of the system (its dynamics) and even a lot of noise would have a hard time making it stop oscillating.

If you have the linear one you must have a system with conjugate poles with zero real part (along the imaginary axis), like,

\$ (s-j8)(s+j8),\$ or \$ (s-j8)(s+j8)(s-j20)(s+j20).\$

That means that any noise to the system, such as an impulse \$ \delta(t) \$, will lead to an oscillation that does not decay. For the system,

$$ H(s) = \frac{1}{(s-j8)(s+j8)(s-j20)(s+j20)}, $$
any impulse input will lead this system to have the following output,
$$ h(t) = a \cos(8t)+b \cos(20t).$$

But, regarding the Barkhausen criterion, it states that at the frequency of oscillation

|------->[ P ]--------> Vout

|

|-------[ B ]<-------- Vin

- \$ |PB| = 1 \$
- \$ \angle PB = 0 \$

  So, for \$ P = \frac{s-1}{(s+1+j)(s+1-j)}\$ and \$ B = k\$ (the gain for a positive feedback), this would oscillate for,
  $$  \text{for }\omega = 2, k \geq 0, ~~ \angle PB = 0, $$
  $$  \text{we must have }\left| \frac{j2-1}{(j2+1+j)(j2+1-j)} k \right| = 1, $$
  $$  \left| \frac{j2-1}{(j2+1+j)(j2+1-j)} k \right| = 1, $$
  $$  \left| \frac{1}{2} k \right| = 1, $$
  $$  k = 2.  $$

Now, if you analyze the closed-loop transfer function you will reach the same result but the algebra to find the necessary \$ k \$ might be a bit harder,

$$  H(s) = \frac{P}{ 1-kP} = \frac{ \frac{s-1}{(s+1+j)(s+1-j)}}{ 1-k \frac{s-1}{(s+1+j)(s+1-j)}} = \frac{s-1}{ (s+1+j)(s+1-j)-k(s-1)},  $$
$$  H(s) = \frac{s-1}{s^2+ (2-k) s +2+k},$$
With poles at,
$$  s_0 = \frac{k-2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{k^2-8k-4}}{2},$$
$$  s_0 = \frac{k-2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{k^2-8k-4}}{2},$$
And with \$ k = 2\$ you get a pole at the imaginary axis (zero real part).
$$  s_0 = 2j, s_0 = -2j.$$

Comment: Is k the loop gain here? It’s equal to 2, but the Barkhausen criterion says loop gain should be equal to 1. What is my mistake here?

Comment: The loop gain is \$ |P(\omega)B(\omega)| \$ and not just the feedback gain \$ k\$, if you look at the condition "\$ |PB| = 1 \$" I do have a loop gain equal to 1.

Comment: So do you mean the Barkhausen criterion is equivalent to having the poles on the imag axis? Also, how did you know that it would oscillate for omega = 2?

Comment: For linear systems time-invariant it is, for other types of system it probably isn't. The linear system will only oscillate with feedback if it has those imaginary poles on the closed-loop transfer function. You can find the omega value by solving for the angle condition, that is what I did, but did not include the calculations for it.

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer without any mathematics:

"*...could you briefly explain how a nonlinearity can help sustain the oscillations? Also about the Bakhausen criterion, why should the loop gain be equal to 1? In a closed loop system, the loop gain that places the poles on the imaginary axis can be anything depending on the transfer function of the open loop system*"

- Let me start with a sentence which like most: A harmonic oscillator for sinusoidal signals must be as linear as possible....and for this purpose it must contain a non-linear (amplitude-dependent) part or circuitry.

From system theory we know that for rising (falling) amplitudes the poles of the closed-loop system must be in the right half (left half) of the s-plane. Hence, for constant amplitudes the poles should be directly on the imaginary axis (theoretically !!). However, for a safe start of oscillations at t=0 the poles should have a small positive real part (right half). This requirement is identical with a loop gain slightly above unity. More than that, this is the only practical method to cope for the uncertainties and parts tolerance for each real circuit.

As a consequence, the oscillation will start with continuously rising amplitudes.If we do not allow hard-limiting of the signal caused by the maximum possible voltage of the device (supply voltage), we need a kind of "soft-limiting" effect. For this purpose, a non-linear device is needed which (for rising amplitudes) continuously reduces the loop gain and shifting the poles back to the imaginary axis (diodes, thermistors, controllable FET-resistance, AGC circuitry,...).

However, due to several time constants within the whole circuit the closed-loop poles will be NOT fixed at the imag. axis but will swing around this axis (between the left and the right half of the s-plane). Hence, in most cases the produced signal will carry a slight amplitude modulation - and it is the main task for the designer to keep this amplitude variation within acceptable limits (proper selection for the time constants and the excess loop gain).

- Why unity loop gain (Barkhausen criterion)? It should be noted that this criterion is a necessary one only - not a sufficient criterion.

"Unity loop gain" means that - for a single specified frequency only - the complex forward gain of the amplifier can exactly compensate the damping and the phase shift of the feedback network. With other words: The amplifier can produce an output voltage Vout and - at the same time - the corresponding  input voltage which is necessary to allow this value Vout. The amplifier does not need an external signal to produce this output signal Vout.